# Should I re-establish contact with an opportunity that seems to have fizzled?

Tags: united-states, hiring-process, job-change

Back in February, I interviewed with a company for new position. It seemed like a great fit and the interviews on the day all seemed to go well. After the interviews, the hiring manager told me the team was very impressed with me and I was asked for references. But then, things went quiet for a week or so. A follow-up call with the hiring manager let me learn that the projects for which I was being considered weren't signed yet and so it would make more sense to wait until they were.

Then, COVID-19 became our new reality. I have since had no contact with the hiring manager, but it is now about the time of year where she stated those projects should have become active. Is there any point in reaching back out to her to understand if things can be picked back up from where they left off, or do I write this off assuming they weren't actually going to make me an offer?

(edit) The position that I had applied for (along with several others that I remember being posted at the time) are no longer posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat I think the amount of time passed and specific circumstances make this situation a little unique compared to the one in the question you linked. But thank you for pointing me toward it -- it somehow wasn't one of the auto-suggested ones when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any point in reaching back out to her to understand if
>   things can be picked back up from where they left off, or do I write
>   this off assuming they weren't actually going to make me an offer?

If you do nothing then the very real risk is that they won't contact you.

Touching base has very little risk: They can ignore it; they can respond back politely; they can get upset and respond unprofessionally; or they can start a conversation that can lead to an offer.

Even if this would have been the time of the year those projects would have been starting, it is possible that they have been delayed. Without knowing those details there is no way to know the correct time to contact them or the best way to approach the conversation.

Comment: +1 Absolutely this. The OP needs more data to help him decide on the best course of action. Speculation does not cut it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was thinking that perhaps timing my communication with the hiring manager to coincide with when my current company (and thus hopefully theirs) are back to more regular operations might be appropriate and also allow any additional delays to have settled out.